# What is a multisignature address?

Tags: multisignature

What additional advantages would a multi signature address give?

Can it create multiple nodes for blockchain broadcasting?

Comment: @TaylorGerring Pl read the question completely. I don't think both of them are duplicates of each other :)

Comment: Thanks @Dawny33, I do agree they're not exactly the same, however I address how "multisignature" addresses differ between Bitcoin and Ethereum in the linked duplciate. Strictly speaking, "multisignature" is a Bitcoin concept not directly translatable to Ethereum, thus making the question a bit nonsensical.

Comment: In its current form I agree that this question is already answered in the linked duplicate.  If it can be changed to make it genuinely different we can always vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multisignature in the bitcoin sense would typically mean you need n-of-m private keys to sign a transaction to make it valid. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multisignature

In the Ethereum sense, Multisignature can mean anything. From the Ethereum Wallet (Mist): "This is a joint wallet controlled by **3** owners. You can send up to **100** ether per day. Any transaction over that daily limit requires the confirmation of **2** owners." (After this, you enter the Owner Addresses. Bold values are editable in the gui.)

That is just the default multisig contract in Ethereum Wallet (Mist), but you can make a contract that has any arbitrary logic if you have the programming knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no native multisig address mechanism in Ethereum. Multisig in Ethereum terms is a simple smart contract that checks all necessary signatures and if conditions defined by a contract are met the contract release funds. 
Please follow [this](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol) example to understand how that works.